# How to check non standard object equivalence in golang template

Tags: go, gocql

I am outputting a dropdown list using a html template, as follows:

```
{{range .Organisations}}
 <option value="{{.Uuid}}">{{.Name}}</option>
{{end}}
```

I want to indicate that one of the items should be selected by doing an `eq` comparator. The only potential complication I am aware of is that the `.Uuid` is a `*gocql.UUID`, I am trying to do this:

```
{{range .Organisations}}
 <option value="{{.Uuid}}"{{if eq $.Contact.Organisation .Uuid}} selected="selected"{{end}}>{{.Name}}</option>
{{end}}
```

But it results in the following error message:

> page:32:36: executing "submit_scholarship" at : error calling eq: invalid type for comparison

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two suggestions. Firstly, I assume `$.Contact.Organisation` is a struct which you are comparing with whatever `Uuid` is .. I assume thats a string. Also, you may consider moving the logic here into a property of the template model itself. Then you can render `selected="selected"` only for the actual selected item .. but `selected=""` for the rest.

Comment: Thanks, including a `Select()` function on the struct is how I normally do it. However I really want to avoid having view logic in my data model code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

eq only works on basic types. You can add a custom function to do this.
http://play.golang.org/p/rkYnlqmeLA

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "os"
)

type s struct {
    Name []byte
    Uuid []byte
}

func main() {
    data := s{[]byte("aa"), []byte("aa")}

    funcMap := template.FuncMap{
        "equals": func(a []byte, b []byte) bool {
            return string(a) == string(b)
        },
    }

    var html = `{{if equals .Name .Uuid }}hi{{end}}`
    tmpl, _ := template.New("test").Funcs(funcMap).Parse(html)

    err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data)
    if err != nil {
        println(err.Error())
    }

}
```